# Linux script to parse each line, check the regex and modify the line

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, csv

I'm trying to write a linux bash script that takes in input a csv file with lines written in the following format (something can be blank):

```
something,something,,number,something,something,something,something,something,something,,,
something,something.something,,number,something,something,something,something,something,something,,,
```

and i have to have as output the following format (if the lines contains `.` it has to separate the two substring in substring1,substring2 and remove one `,` character, else do nothing)

```
something,something,,number,something,something,something,something,something,something,,,
something,something,something,number,something,something,something,something,something,something,,,
```

I tried to parse each line of the file and check if it respects a regex, but the command starts a never ending loop (don't know why) and morevor don't know how to divide the substring to have as output substring1,substring2

```
for f in /filepath/filename.csv
do
            while read p; do
            if [[$p == .\..]] ; then echo $p; fi
            done <$f
done
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You input doesn't contain DOT and your expected output is same as input

Answer (score 0):

I can't provide you with a working code at the moment but a piece of quick advice:
1. Try with tool called sed
2. Learn about "capture groups" for regex to get info on how to divide the text based on expressions.

Answer (score 0):

To separate strings AWK will be useful

```
    echo "Hello.world" | awk -F"." '{print "STR1="$1", STR2="$2 }'
```

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

As your task is more about transforming unrelated lines of text than of parsing fields of csv formatted files, `sed` is indeed the tool to go.

Learning to use `sed` properly, even for the most basic tasks, is synonym to learning regular expressions. The following invocation of `sed` command transforms your input sample to your expected output:

```
sed 's/\.\([^,]*\),/,\1/g' input.csv >output.csv
```

In the above example, `s///` is the replacement command.
From the manpage:

> s/regexp/replacement/
>
> Attempt  to match regexp against the pattern space.  If successful,
>   replace that portion matched with replacement. [...]

Explaining the regexp and replacement of the above command is probably out of the scope for the question, so I'll finish my answer here... Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i managed to use regexp, but the following command seems not working again:

```
sed '\([^,]*\),\([^,]*\)\.\([^,]*\),,\([^,]*\),\([^,]*\),\([^,]*\),\([^,]*\),\([^,]*\),\([^,]*\),\([^,]*\),\([^,]*\),\([^,]*\),/\1,\2,\3,\4,\5,\6,\7,\8,\9,\10,\11,\12,'
```

sed: -e expression #1, char 125: unknown command: `\'